# UnknownError calling /beta/invitations

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-api-apps

I must be missing something obvious.  When posting to the beta API https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/invitations (api ref: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/invitation_post), I get

> {
>     "error": {
>       "code": "UnknownError",
>       "message": "",
>       "innerError": {
>         "request-id": "e41b0eab-c39c-4cf8-9034-341c81fc722c",
>         "date": "2017-01-14T19:26:55"
>       }
>     }
>   }

Here's my code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GraphClient g = new GraphClient();
            Console.WriteLine(g.SendPost(g.authContext, g.credential).Result);
        }        
    }

    public class GraphClient
    {
        public AuthenticationContext authContext;
        public ClientCredential credential;
        public GraphClient()
        {
            this.authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/MYTENANT.onmicrosoft.com");
            this.credential = new ClientCredential("MYCLIENTID", "MYCLIENTSECRET");
        }
        public async Task<string> SendPost(AuthenticationContext authContext, ClientCredential credential)
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", credential);

            HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/invitations");
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
            request.Content = new StringContent("{\"invitedUserEmailAddress\": \"MYEMAIL@MYDOMAIN.COM\",\"inviteRedirectUrl\": \"https://MYWEBSITE.COM\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await http.SendAsync(request);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks!  I can do other /beta commands just fine.  For example GETting https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users returns a user list in my tenant, as expected.

-Dan

Comment: Are you sending the Content-Type header to tell it to expect json? Not familiar with this language, so not sure if request.content is setting that along with its encoding.

Comment: it's there, at the very end of the line that starts "request.Content = new StringContent....."

Comment: If you try the same request using Graph Explorer, do you get the same error or something different? Also is this a 500 error? I asked someone to look through the trace logs to understand the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the logs, you are receiving a 401 error response, which means that the caller was not granted the required permissions to call the API. You'll need to follow the guidance here: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/invitation_post which indicates that you need Directory.ReadWrite.All or User.ReadWrite.All (although I'm not sure the latter one works or is available right now).

We've also filed a bug to fix this error message (sorry about this - we do need to do much better here).

Hope this helps,

Comment: thanks for a quick response!  permissions was definitely the problem.  turns out i had granted the correct permission in the portal, but i wasn't clicking the "Grant Permissions" button.  dur.  thx again.

Comment: dan, for the record, this invitation manager does not actually invite the user via email, correct?  It's our responsibility to actually send out the email?

Comment: nevermind, i found the reference to "sendInvitationMessage": "true" in the invitation manager doc.  seems like you should have that in the invitation_post doc, but what do i know :)

Comment: This is mentioned, but it's not in the example, because typically we show the example with ONLY the required properties.  sendInvitationMessage is not a required property.  However, please feel free to file an issue about this on GitHub https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues.